# Javascript: window.pageYOffset not working if in variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a problem:

```
alert(window.pageYOffset);
```

Returns a correct value, whereas:

```
var oben = window.pageYOffset;
alert(oben);
```

Returns 0.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help! :)

#### My specs

- Windows 7 x64
- Google Chrome, newest version

Comment: Are you actually invoking these immediately after eachother as suggested by what's written here, or is there some kind of delay before the `alert`, after the `var`

Comment: @PaulS. There is no delay between setting the `var` and the alert.

Comment: jsfiddle or it didn't happen.

Comment: @RichieHindle See http://jsfiddle.net/2EZmq/1/.

Comment: @toothbrush: OK, but what happened to "There is no delay between setting the var and the alert"?  Your fiddle has a delay.

Comment: @RichieHindle OK. How about http://jsfiddle.net/2EZmq/2/?

Comment: @toothbrush In your jsfiddle you can clearly see what my problem is :|

Comment: @user3735411 OK. So can't you use `oben()`, as in my answer?

Comment: `a = 1; b = a; a = 2;` After this, b is still 1. That's how variables work in JavaScript. `a` and `b` are completely unrelated, except that they happen to point to the same value. Pointing `a` at a new value does not affect `b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers are primitive values in JavaScript.

Therefore, `oben` is set to whatever `window.pageYOffset` is at the time.

Perhaps what you want is something like this:

```
var oben = function() {
    return window.pageYOffset;
};

alert(oben());
```

Just use `oben()` anywhere you've got (or would put) `oben`.

Comment: How does that explain the behaviour?

Comment: @RichieHindle Sorry. I've added more explanation.

Comment: If we're code golfing it, why not do `var o = {get ben () {return window.pageYOffset;}};`, then you're one digit closer with just `alert(o.ben);`

Comment: @PaulS. But we're not code-golfing it. If I was, I'd prefer `o=x=>window.pageYOffset`.

Comment: @toothbrush Ok great start but what do I have to do so I can use `oben` for further calculations? Say I wanna do `var whatever = oben / anothervar`?

Comment: @user3735411 What do you mean, `oben / anothervar`? Do you mean that if `oben > x`, `whatever` should be `anothervar`?

Comment: @toothbrush No, I want `whatever` to be the result of `oben` divided by `anothervar`. `whatever = oben() / anothervar;` doesn't work.

Comment: @user3735411 `whatever = oben() / anothervar`.

Comment: @toothbrush As I stated above, this does not work. My `alert(whatever)` responds with `0`.

Comment: @user3735411 Please edit your question and add your browser, browser version, operating system and operating system version.

Comment: @toothbrush Updated the question. Thanks for your help! Do you maybe know a better way to divide the current scrollposition (in px) by a certain number or variable?

Comment: @user3735411 Go to http://jsfiddle.net/2EZmq/4/, scroll down the red background, and click the "What is `window.pageYOffset`?" button. The alert shows the current value of `window.pageYOffset`, divided by `anothervar`. Is that what you want?

Comment: `0` divided by any number except `0` will return `0`.